# Can't convert Pillow Image to numpy array or to RGB mode

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to load a Dataset of PNGs. The PNGs are stored in "L" mode (8bit per pixel monochrome).

1. When trying to convert them with  `image.convert('RGB')`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 180, in load
    seek = self.load_seek
AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_seek'
```

2. If I leave that step out and convert them to a numpy array directly with `np.array(image)`, I get a numpy array with  `dtype=object` and length 1, with the only Pillow Image object as its content.

Comment: what version of Pillow are you using? try updating the version

Comment: I have tried both 8.0.1 and 8.1.0, but the update didn't change anything

Comment: Please share the *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* (i.e. runnable code) that Stack Overflow requires, along with the image that fails. Thank you.

Comment: your numpy array shold be of dtype: uint8 
(i.e.  image1_array dtype :  uint8)